# Почему при преобразовании файла в массив байтов некоторые значения отрицательные?

Tags: java, переполнение

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path P = Paths.get("D:\\1.txt");
    byte[] Li = Files.readAllBytes(P);

    for (int i = 0; i < Li.length; i++)
        System.out.println(Li[i]);
}
```

Вывод:
-47
-21
-32
-30
-32
106
104
121
Почему некоторые числа со знаком минус ?

Comment: Ну что, ваша проблема решилась? Напомню, если ответ решил вашу проблему, то стоит нажать на стрелку вверх и галочку рядом с ним.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Вывод: `-47 -21 -32 -30 -32 106 104 121` Почему некоторые числа со
>   знаком минус?

Скорее всего, это происходит из-за [переполнения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). У типа `byte` диапазон значений от -128 до 127. Некоторые значения байтов больше 127, поэтому происходит переполнение отдельных значений в массиве. Вам надо заменить `byte[]` на `int[]`. Массив *байтов* не означает, что его надо хранить в `byte[]`.

Вот рабочий код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path P = Paths.get("D:\\1.txt");

    byte[] Li = Files.readAllBytes(P);
    int[] intArr = new int[Li.length];
    for(int i = 0; i<Li.length; i++)
        intArr[i] = Li[i];

    for (int i = 0; i < Li.length; i++)
        System.out.println(intArr[i]);
}
```

Переполнение происходит примерно как на картинке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если значение(например, 140) больше максимального значения в `byte`(127), то остаток(`140-127=13`) "заполняется" снизу в `byte`. Так как сначала идут отрицательные значения, остаток "заполняет" отрицательные значения. Если остаток >128, то он дойдет до положительных значений.

Comment: Спасибо за рисунок, теперь понял как происходит переполнение, только вот int[] вместо byte[],использовать не получается, выводится ошибка с предложением изменить обратно int на byte.

Comment: @Алексей я почитал javadocs, там написано, что не стоит использовать этот метод для получения массива байтов больших файлов

Comment: @Алексей обновил ответ

Comment: @AntonSorokin, привет, а как обратно массив с байтами int[] перевести в строку? т.е. восстановить фразу например

Answer (score 0):

Отрицательные цифры это просто отображение байта в виде знакового десятичного числа. Один байт состоит из восьми бит, если мы рассматриваем байт как знаковое число, то первый бит служит для определения знака. Пример отображения каждого байта в виде бинарного, десятичного беззнаковго и десятичного знакового числа:

```
for (Byte b: "Hello Мир".getBytes()) System.out.printf("%10s: %5d - %d%n", Integer.toBinaryString(Byte.toUnsignedInt(b)), Byte.toUnsignedInt(b), b)
```

Если есть Java 9, то можешь эту строчку выполнить в jshell.